# Deriving a differential equation from a given solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a function defined by

$$ G(w) = \int_{0}^{\left(1+ \frac{a}{b}e^w\right)^{-1}}  x^{b-1}(1-x)^{a-1} dx ~.\tag 1 $$

I am trying to find a differential equation whose solution is given by(1). I am able to come up with the following:

$$ G'(w) = - \left( \frac{a}{b}e^w \right)^a \left( 1 + \frac{a}{b}e^w \right)^{-(a+b)}~. \tag 2$$

My question is the following:
Is (2) the best I can do?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: How are you measuring the "goodness" of an equation?  In other words, you ask if (2) is the best you can do; what type of equation would you consider "better" than that?

Comment: @tilper What I mean is whether (2) is the only differential equation that can be gotten from (1)?

Comment: No. The equation you need has no constants of integration $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @RafaBudría Please, I don't understand your comment. Can you explain a bit. Thanks.

Comment: e.g. $y=ax+b$ with $a$ and $b$ some constants. Differentiating twice $y''=0$ an equation satisfied by $y$ and has not the constants.